# sync only particular folder in Google drive desktop app in particular computer

Tags: windows-8, sync, google-drive

How to sync only particular folder in Google drive desktop app in particular computer (os is windows 8)? e.g. If I have 2 computers I want to synce all files and folders in one computer but I want to synce only one folder in second computer.

There is no setting menu and preferences menu is also disabled.
[Google drive menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QfLp.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you click the google drive icon in the taskbar, in the upcoming info screen at the top right you can click the three dots. There is a menu 'Preferences' which allows you to choose which folders to sync selectively.

Comment: As soon as installation finishes, it asks for email address and starts downloading all the files and folders immediately.

Comment: I have updated the question with the menu pic.

Comment: On first run, it seems to be grayed out. Try to quit it and restart, on the second run it should be chooseable.

Answer (score 0):

After you sign-in to your account only preference option is enabled. After signing the sync process will start to download all files. You can pause that action and click preference it will show which folder you need to sync under the "Sync options" tab.

You should select the "Sync only these folders(n MB selected)" and below this you have to check only the particular folder or sub folder to sync to Google drive. Other folders will be deleted from you local if you have downloaded already but will stay in your Google drive.

Any modification made to this sync folder under Google Drive directory will also be updated and synced automatically. Hope this helps.